# How can we remove certain folder name from the path and return new path?

Tags: c#, absolute-path

I have a path:

```
 "C:\\Users\\dev\\Test\\TestResults\\Config\\Report.xml"
```

I need to check if this path has folder "TestResults", if it has then I need to remove this and return new path as

```
"C:\\Users\\dev\\Test\\Config\\Report.xml"
```

I know I can achieve this using trim and split. But just to make sure I pick up a right choice. What is the best way of achieving this?

Any help really appriciated.

Comment: `path.Replace("\\TestResults\\","")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would not use string replace method in this case. Why?

e.g. :

```
string path = "C:\\Users1\\Users2\\Users122\\Users13\\Users133\\filename.xml";
path = path.Replace("\\TestResults", string.Empty);
// you will get "C:\Users222333\filename.xml"
```

that is not what you expected.

so how to fix this,

```
path = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(),      
           path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Where(x=> x!="Users1").ToArray()));

//C:\Users2\Users122\Users13\Users133\filename.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method like;

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\dev\\Test\\TestResults\\Config\\Report.xml";
path = path.Replace("\\TestResults", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Output will be;

```
C:\Users\dev\Test\Config\Report.xml
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/7mUKUc).